# Пакеты в андроид-приложении с паттерном MVP

Tags: android, шаблоны-проектирования

Какая структура пакетов должна быть в андроид-приложении с паттерном MVP?
Три корневых пакета: model, view, presenter? 
Не превратит ли такой подход паттерн MVP в ААА (Activity, Activity, Activity), когда все Activity будут находиться в пакете view?
Нужно делить активити по разным пакетам внутри пакета view, или лучше делать как-то по-другому?

Comment: Не думаю что паттерн MVP диктует какую то четкую структуру пакетов. Это всего лишь шаблон разделения логики на слои. Не стоит придумывать какие то жесткие требования и стараться следовать им на 100%. Сделайте так, как вам удобно.

Comment: @temq, как раз таки нужно следовать жестким правилам, это же паттерн. А паттерны для этого и существуют

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как хороший вариант, придерживаться можно следующей схемы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Структура будет примерно такая:

```
-- data
---- network
------ ApiHelper
------ IApiHelper
---- prefs
------ PreferencesHelper
------ IPreferencesHelper
---- DataManager
---- IDataManager
-- ui
---- login
------ LoginActivity
------ LoginPresenter
------ LoginView
---- registration
------ RegistrationActivity
------ RegistrationPresenter
------ RegistrationView
```

Но нужно учитывать именно ваше приложение, учитывая его требования и задачи

Comment: А не лучше ли разместить *View в ui/view, активности в ui/activity, а презентеры вообще вынести на уровень всесте с data и ui?

Comment: @Flippy это тоже как вариант, но так как у одной Activity одна View и один Presenter, то редактируя к примеру экран регистрации, считаю удобнее открыть один пакет и уже в нем вносить изменения по экрану, вместо того что бы перемещаться по разным + в в этом пакете можно удобно хранить другие классы относящиеся только к этому экрану.